# How do I set the color of an individual point in an Excel scatterplot using .NET?

Tags: .net, excel, interop

I am trying to set the color of individual points in an Excel scatterplot through C#, but can't get it to work. Here is the code I am currently using. Note that the MarkerStyle and MarkerSize part of the code works - so my issue is really about color. I suspect I am missing a cast somewhere.

var point = (Excel.Point)series.Points(index);

point.MarkerStyle = XlMarkerStyle.xlMarkerStyleSquare;
point.MarkerSize = 8;

point.MarkerBackgroundColor = 10;
point.MarkerForegroundColor = 10;

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are expecting to set a color index rather than an RGB (I say that because you are setting it to 10). I believe MarkerForegroundColor is expecting an RGB color. Did you mean to set MarkerForegroundColorIndex?

Comment: Thank you so much, you are totally right: a RGB code is expected. I thought this was failing, because the values I was using were too small, and it all looked black to me.

The design and/or documentation of this interface is truly perplexing; MarketBackgrounColorIndex is expecting an XlColorIndex, which can take 2 values (automatic or none), so I wonder how one uses the default indexes...

Comment: The color index properties are indexes into the 56 color palette in Excel. This is a legacy thing - Excel 2003 and previous versions were limited to a 56 color palette. Excel 2007 can handle 24 bit RGB colors so you are better off setting MarkerForegroundColor to the RGB you want if your users will have Excel 2007.